# Are US Marines deliberately kept under-supplied so that they would be more combat aggressive?

Tags: united-states, psychology, military, war

I watched a TV series named *[Generation Kill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_Kill_(miniseries))* based on the experiences of an embedded reporter during the invasion of Iraq in the 2003.

The US Marines in the series often complain about lacking essential supply such as batteries, decent toilet paper, baby wipes, etc.

When asked why it is like that, an actor playing the (real-life) marine Cpl. Josh Ray Person said:

> To keep us angry. If Marines could get what they needed when they needed it we would be happy and wouldn't ready to kill people all of the time. The Marine Corps is like America's Pitbull. They beat us, mistreat us and every once in awhile, they let us out to attack someone.

Though it's more like a satire than an answer, it still sounds quite convincing.

Do the US Marine Corps sometimes deliberately keep their soldiers under-supplied and uncomfortable/inconvenient in order to keep their aggressiveness high?

Comment: Hard to prove a negative, but I doubt it. It's just dangerous and difficult. "Supplying FOBs became an increasingly dangerous task with roadside IED, VBIED and suicide attacks continuing to plague Coalition forces’ operations as the routes became more regular and insurgents’ tactics improved." [Capability's improving, though.](https://www.army-technology.com/features/featuresafe-and-well-stocked-new-technology-for-todays-forward-operating-bases-4647465/)

Comment: Logistics is hard. News at 11.

Comment: Also what US forces think is poor supply is massive over supply to most other militaries

Comment: "Baby wipes"? I'm curious what use these would be for as I imagine there's not many babies needing wiping.

Comment: @KenY-N nice soft tissues sound like ideal to clean optics and maybe guns as well. And probably cheaper than whatever the Pentagon purchase machine contracts as specialty items for the job.

Comment: @KenY-N AFAIK they are widely used in the military as a replacement for a decent shower while you are outside of a base.

Comment: [SPOILER AHEAD!!!] I've finished the show. The real reason behind the lack of supply is that, the regiment in the show served as a diversion from the real objective. That's why the headquarter decided to transfer most of the supply to those who take part in the real battle - those who really need it.

Comment: Interestingly enough, some Star Wars novels establish that the Emperor did this with Vader's health care - keeping him barely alive and in pain to potentize his Dark Side power, as such power feeds on pain, suffering, and desire.

Comment: @KenY-N general cleaning. If you don't have access to running water, baby wipes are the next best thing to keep clean. Needless to say that in a battle situation, keeping clean can be the difference between life or death (or permanent dismemberment)